# (matlab) unique variable name from string

Tags: string, matlab, vector, import

I have a simple script to import some spectroscopy data from files with some base filename (YYYYMMDD) and a header.  My current method pushes the actual spectral intensities to some vector 'rawspectra' and I can call the data by `rawspectra{m,n}.data(q,r)

In the script, I specify by hand the base filename and save it as a string 'filebase'.

I would like to append the name of the rawspectra vector with the filebase so I might be able to use the script to import files acquired on different dates into the same workspace without overwriting the rawspectra vector (and also allowing for easy understanding of which vectors are attached to which experimental conditions.  I can easily do this by manually renaming a vector, but I'd rather make this automatic.

My importation script follows:

```
%for the importation of multiple sequential files, starting at startfile
%and ending at numfiles.  All raw scans are subsequently plotted.

numfiles = input('How many spectra?');
startfile = input('What is the starting file number?');
numberspectra = numfiles - (startfile - 1);
filebase = strcat(num2str(input('what is the base file number?')),'_');
rawspectra = cell(startfile, numberspectra);



for k= startfile:numberspectra
filename = strcat(filebase,sprintf('%.3d.txt', k));
%eval(strcat(filebase,'rawspectra')){k} = importdata(filename); - This does not work.
rawspectra{k} = importdata(filename);
figure;
plot(rawspectra{1,k}.data(:,1),rawspectra{1,k}.data(:,2))
end
```

If any of you can help me out with what should be a seemingly simple task, I would be very appreciative. Basically, I want 'filebase' to go in front of 'rawspectra' and then increment that by k++ within the loop.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just

```
rawspectra(k) = importdata(filename);
rawspectra(k).filebase = filebase;
```

Comment: thank you for the response.  While this allows me to tag the data sets with the base file name, it will still overwrite the 'rawspectra' variable when I import a dataset with a different base file name.  This doesn't fit my needs, but you did teach me something more about matlab, so thanks for that.

Comment: @user8307: You're welcome. I'm a bit confused by your answer, but probably i've not got your question right. Anyway, the generic approach is to create an (structure) array which can hold the data vectors and filenames as its elements, and access them using array's index.